# Using INTL to get the full week's days from today

Tags: javascript, intl

I'm trying to get the days of the week from the date of the specific day (e.g today is wednesday so I'd like to get today plus the 7 days after today) using the INTL. I have managed to get today's date but I'm unsure how to get the rest of the days.

```
              function daysForLocale(localeName = 'en', weekday = 'long') {
                const format = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(localeName, { weekday }).format;
                return [...Array(1).keys()]
                  .map((day) => format(new Date()));
              }
              console.log(daysForLocale());
```

output:

```
["Wednesday"]
["Wednesday"]
["Wednesday"]
["Wednesday"]
["Wednesday"]
["Wednesday"]
["Wednesday"]
```

Desired Output

```
["Thursday"]
["Friday"]
["Saturday"]
["Sunday"]
["Monday"]
["Tuesday"]
["Wednesday"]
```

Comment: `new Date()` always returns today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code.

```js
    function daysForLocale(localeName = 'en', weekday = 'long') {
        const format = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(localeName, { weekday }).format;
        const today = new Date();
        return [...Array(7).keys()]
          .map((val, index) => [format(new Date(today.getTime() + 3600 * 24 * 1000 * (index + 1)))]);
    }
    console.log(daysForLocale());
```

Comment: Thanks for your help this gets me all the days in one array.
I'm looking to get each day in an array i.e ["Thursday"] ["Friday"]

Comment: I have updated this code. Please check again.

Comment: that worked thank you so much, I'll mark your answer as correct.
For my own learning can you please walk me through what you did?

Comment: yes can you walk me through the changes you made any why it works?

Comment: With loop of index(0~6) I increased the date of today by (index + 1) day. So if today is Monday, the array is filled from Tuesday to Monday.